# Android - ListView with 2 textView's get which one was clicked

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a list view with that I have set up with 2 textview inside of it, on is on the right and one is on the left, and I want to set an onClickListerner for them and get the text of the one that was clicked, and also the row of the list view that was clicked.

I have been able to set up to get the row that was clicked but now I need help finding out which textview in the row was clicked.

Here is my set up for the cell in the list view:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text1"
        android:id="@+id/1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"

        android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text2"
        android:id="@+id/2"
        android:minHeight="60dp"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:gravity="center"
 />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my MainActivity.java with the set up list view and what I have tried so far.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    populateCarList();
    populateListView();
    registerClickCallback();

    private void populateCarList() {
    userDiningHall.add(new DiningHall("hall1", open1));
    userDiningHall.add(new DiningHall("hall2", open2));
    userDiningHall.add(new DiningHall("hall3", open3));
    userDiningHall.add(new DiningHall("hall4", open4));
}

private void populateListView() {
    ArrayAdapter<DiningHall> adapter = new MyListAdapter();
    ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.homeListView);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}

//THIS GETS WHAT ROW WAS CLICKED

private void registerClickCallback() {
    ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.homeListView);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,View ViewClicked, int position, long id) {
            DiningHall clickedDiningHall = userDiningHall.get(position);
            String message = "You clicked position " + position + " which is dining hall " +
                    clickedDiningHall.getDiningHallName();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });


}

private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DiningHall> {
    public MyListAdapter() {
        super(MainActivity.this, R.layout.home_item_view, userDiningHall);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View itemView = convertView;
        if (itemView == null) {
            itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.home_item_view, parent, false);
        }
        //Find the dining hall
        DiningHall currentDiningHall = userDiningHall.get(position);

        //Fill the view
        TextView diningHallText = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemDiningHallTextView);
        diningHallText.setText(currentDiningHall.getDiningHallName());

        TextView openText = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemOpenTextView);
        openText.setText(currentDiningHall.getDiningHallOpen());


        return itemView;
    }
}
```

How can I get what row was clicked and what textview was clicked?

Thanks for the help in advance. :)

Comment: set different onClickListener on each textView in getView()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the same `View.OnClickListener` for both `TextView`s. Then simply check the id of the clicked `View` in `onClick(View v)` by calling `v.getId()`.

Answer (score 0):

you can set simply setOnclickListner for both TextViews and also set OnItemclickLister in listview